# How to draw vertical sinewave in Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, waterfall, sine-wave

I have made a flowing water in Opengl and now wants it to convert in the form of waterfall. For water i used sine wave and for waterfall i want to convert those horizontal sine waves into vertical sine waves. i have tried swapping positions of x and y but nothing got displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for(y=50;y<=-30;y+=inc)

The condition above is never true (if *inc* is greater than zero), so you do not see anything.

You should check the range and *inc*, probably it should look like this:

```
for(y=-30;y<=50;y+=inc)
```